When should we close a question as "seeking assistance in developing a trading strategy"?
I see amongst the close reasons:

Questions seeking assistance in developing a trading strategy are off-topic as they are unlikely to be useful to other readers.

That sounds very vague to me. Many questions on this website could be seen as aiming to develop trading strategies (that's the job of quite a few quants after all). Also, "developing" could mean either implementing coding-wise, or mathematically.
When should we close a question as seeking assistance in developing a trading strategy? 
Some examples of upvoted questions that seem to me as about developing trading strategies just looking around for a few minutes:

Is my trading strategy search methodology sound?
How to identify technical analysis chart patterns algorithmically?
How to normalize technical indicators for machine learning?
Whites Reality Check for Pair Trading
Statistical significance of a pair trading strategy
Using alpha to evaluate trading strategy
Categories of systematic trading strategies?
Usage of Bollinger bands
The Basis of Using Technical Indicators as Inputs
What is the minimum history data size to get an accurate EMA/ MACD for latest history point
How to identify technical analysis chart patterns algorithmically?
ARIMA prediction for currencies 
Good books on predictive modeling (for alpha signal research)
Determine trends of data (direction detection or turning point detection)


My anecdotal observation so far is that sufficiently sophisticated questions by practitioners get upvotes while questions suggesting the OP may be a finance neophyte get downvotes and/or closed.

@MatthewGunn Then it means questions seeking assistance in developing a trading strategy are on-topic, and neophyte questions are not.

I made a proposal to remove the reason. Please let yourselves be heard.

This is a good question IMO.
It is beyond dispute that the proportion of quants in the industry involved in the development of trading strategies has seen a sharp increase over the past few years. First because of the recent hype associated to big data/machine learning but also because most of the models used in the derivatives field have now become standard over the years (hence well documented/understood).
To me it seems fair to say that the skills set required to be a good quant has slowly shifted from pure stochastic calculus and numerical analysis towards machine learning and solid programming skills (the latter due to e.g. regulation needs such as FRTB, XVA etc.).
As such, it wouldn't make sense to discard questions related to developing trading strategies in favour of questions related to derivatives pricing/hedging. 
Of course, the question should show at least some effort and be of a sufficient `quality' as noted by @Matthew Gunn, but this should already be the case for all the questions on this site. 
